# Elasticsearch query to get items that were modified more then an hour ago

Tags: date, elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following indexed items in elasticsearch.

```
{
 "_index": "test_index",
 "type": "_doc",
 "_source": {
   "someTitle": "Thank you for your help",
   "lastUpdated": 1640085989000}
},
{
 "_index": "test_index",
 "type": "_doc",
 "_source": {
   "someTitle": "Thank you for your help",
   "lastUpdated": 1640092916012
  }
},
{
 "_index": "test_index",
 "type": "_doc",
 "_source": {
   "someTitle": "Thank you for your help",
   "lastUpdated": 1640092916012
  }
}
```

How to get the items that were updated more than an hour ago based on that `lastUpdated` value? I have been trying some solutions found in internet but most of them are for querying the string but not number field.

Comment: You want items updated exaclty an hour ago? Or you want items before that or maybe after that?

Comment: Hi @TusharShahi, thanks for getting back. I want items that were updated more then  hour ago. In other word, items that are not updated in last 60 mins. Thanks

Comment: Running the query  that are in the answer but sadly not getting any data back. The hits comes as empty array. :(

Comment: Please add your mapping to the question. Also, [lease comment on the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like a `range` query would do the work [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)

The section you are looking for is [range on dates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates)

Your query should look more or less like that:

```
GET /<your index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "lastUpdated": {
        "gte": "now-1h"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure your mapping is right, and that `lastUpdated` has the right format [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html).

Comment: Thank you @Paulo. It works. Had some issue with mapping apparently.

Comment: It can be tricky ☺️ glad to hear you go it to work

Answer (score 0):

ES gives you keywords like `now` and `h` for simple [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) queries. Along with a [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) you should be able to do it:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "lastUpdated": {
        "lt": "now-1h"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Tushar but `"lt": "now-1h"` does not work for some reason but `"gte": "now-1h"` works

Comment: Glad. Please upvote and accept the answer in that case.